# Is there SMS life cycle on android?

Tags: android, sms, send

In my app I need to send a sms from timer task. The code is simple:

```
ArrayList<String> parts = sms.divideMessage(message);
sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phone_numbers[i], null, parts, null, null);
```

Every sms is different, because has time stamp. So the text looks like "10:20 - blah blah"

BUT! the destination phone receives only first message. To explain what I mean let say sender app sent a messages every minute. Works 10 minutes and 10 messages sent (10:20, 10:21, 10:22... 10:29). Destination phone received 10 messages, but all of them the same and the message is the firts one sent (10:20). CatLog in the Eclips shows that "message" composed correctly (time stamp differs).

Perhaps this happens because I use null for both PendingInstances and there should be some routine which confirms/clears/cances/whatever that the first sms sent to let second and others to be sent.

Please help me! I have no idea what to do.

Sender - HTC Desire Z 2.3.3.  Receivers Samsung Galaxy 2 and Nokia lumia 710 (WinPhone 7.5)

Comment: hi dzaga, first count number of messages in  `parts` `ArrayList`  by using `parts.size()`

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It is not a phone OS or model. It is mobile phone operator! I got SIM cards from two other operators available in my region. Now I have 4 SIM cars of operators, let say A,B,C,D. Descibed behavior only appears when sms goes from A to C. A to B, A to D works just fine.